# Radeon 7450 and Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, compatibility, amd-radeon

Is the Radeon HD 7450 graphics card compatible with Windows 8's resolution requirements? It is not listed on the [Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/Home).

Comment: My apologies its a hardware not the software I misunderstood. going to delete my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 requires at least 1024 x 768 screen resolution, if your monitor supports it, then you don't have a problem, your graphics card will run at that resolution(even 6 year old integrated graphics support huge resolutions).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not if there is a WDDM driver for it--the latest [Catalyst 12.8](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalystSoftwareSuiteVersion128ReleaseNotes.aspx) package does contain WDDM drivers for Windows 8.  The Radeon HD 7450 can display full HD and beyond and has sufficient DirectX support, so I don't expect a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only graphic card requirement for windows 8 is [directx 9 compatibility](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/system-requirements) along with WDDM, and the 7450 has both.

Unfortunately, AMD website doesn't list it anymore so I cannot provide a reference page.